# How to check net TCP wcf service is connected

Tags: c#, wcf

Command to check whether net TCP wcf Windows service is running?

I was trying with proxy to the wcf and getting timeout exception while calling a contract. So unable to confirm whether service is running or not

Comment: Announcement functionality will be helpful , do some workaround by referring this link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/dd483353(v=vs.100)

Comment: I am getting the exception when I have call back contract on service

Answer (score 1):

The following ways could achieve you want.
1.  Use the Netstat  windows command to check whether the port is listening over TCP.
For example, Check whether port 1900 is listening over TCP.
[image: netstat]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/netstat
2.  OnlineAnnouncement/offlineAnnouncement notification by using UDP discovery endpoint.
When server is online, it could send online announcement by using UDP discovery endpoint. 
I have made an example, wish it is useful to you.
**Server.**

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:1900");
            NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
            using (ServiceHost sh=new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService),uri))
            {
                sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), binding, "");
                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb;
                smb = sh.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
                if (smb == null)
                {
                    smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior()
                    {
                    };
                    sh.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
                }
                ServiceDiscoveryBehavior sdb = new ServiceDiscoveryBehavior();
                sdb.AnnouncementEndpoints.Add(new UdpAnnouncementEndpoint());
                sh.Description.Behaviors.Add(sdb);
                sh.AddServiceEndpoint(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());

                Binding binding1 = MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexTcpBinding();
                sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), binding1, "mex");
                sh.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Service is ready...");

                Console.ReadLine();
                sh.Close();
            }

        }
    }
    [ServiceContract(Namespace ="mydomain")]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract(Name ="AddInt")]
        int Add(int x, int y);

    }
    public class MyService : IService
    {
        public int Add(int x, int y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }
}
```

**Client.**

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.Title = "Start client first";

        AnnouncementService annsvc = new AnnouncementService();
        annsvc.OnlineAnnouncementReceived += OnlineRec;
        annsvc.OfflineAnnouncementReceived += OfflineRec;
        using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(annsvc))
        {
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(new UdpAnnouncementEndpoint());
            host.Open();
            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    private static void OfflineRec(object sender, AnnouncementEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\nService is offline, service address：{e.EndpointDiscoveryMetadata.Address.Uri}");
    }

    private static void OnlineRec(object sender, AnnouncementEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\nService is online, service address：{e.EndpointDiscoveryMetadata.Address.Uri}");
    }
```

**Result.**
[image: UdpDiscoveryEndpoint]
**Official document.**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/dd483353(v=vs.100)
Actually, we could get the service status by the service metadata address. for the above example, we could detect the service status with inputting net.tcp://localhost:1900/mex in Adding service reference dialog.
[image]
3.  Use notepad to log the status. Please refer to my example.

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:1000");
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
ServiceHost sh = null;

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), uri);
    ServiceMetadataBehavior smb;
    smb = sh.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
    if (smb==null)
    {
        smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior
        {
            HttpGetEnabled = true
        };
        sh.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
    }
    sh.Open();
    WriteLog($"Service is ready at {DateTime.Now.ToString("hh-mm-ss")}");
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    if (sh!=null&&sh.State==CommunicationState.Opened)
    {
        sh.Close();
        WriteLog($"Service is closed at {DateTime.Now.ToString("hh-mm-ss")}");
    }
}
public static void WriteLog(string text)
{
    using (StreamWriter sw=File.AppendText(@"D:\log.txt"))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(text);
        sw.Flush();
    }
}
```

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.